# JMH - Lower-level benchmarking

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking, jmh

I'm using JMH to benchmark JUnit tests.

My benchmarks:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

public class Benchmarks {
        @Benchmark
        public void bmUnitTest1() {
                UnitTests.UnitTest1();
        }

        @Benchmark
        public void bmUnitTest2() {
                UnitTests.UnitTest2();
        }
}
```

My benchmark runner:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.results.format.ResultFormatType;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.TimeValue;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BenchmarkRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(Benchmarks.class.getSimpleName())
                .mode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
                .resultFormat(ResultFormatType.CSV)
                .result("target/test-classes/benchmarkcsv/BM " + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".csv")
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .warmupIterations(3)
                .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
                .measurementIterations(3)
                .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
                .timeout(TimeValue.seconds(5))
                .forks(1)
                .warmupForks(1)
                .threads(1)
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }
}
```

Currently I'm getting performance metrics on the whole unit test. I was wondering if it's possible to see these performance metrics on a lower level.

---

*Example:*

UnitTest1 has multiple function calls. Function1 takes 10ms, Function2 takes 20ms.

Instead of seeing this (simplified):

```
UnitTest1: 30ms/op
```

I'd like to see this:

```
UnitTest1: 30ms/op
        Function1: 10ms/op
        Function2: 20ms/op
```

Can I do this in JMH? If not, are there any alternatives I could use to benchmark JUnit tests?

Comment: Can profiling be a better fit for your needs? If so, [Java Flight Recorder](https://www.baeldung.com/java-flight-recorder-monitoring) could be a good option.

Comment: Write a benchmark for function1 and another benchmark for function2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JMH has several profilers that can be enabled while running benchmarks. See [JMHSample_35_Profilers](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/blob/master/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_35_Profilers.java) for details.

One of them is `async` profiler based on [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) project. It can do exactly what you want - show which methods called by your unit test take most CPU time (with stack traces!)

To enable this profiler, call `OptionsBuilder.addProfiler(AsyncProfiler.class, "output=flamegraph")`, or (if running from a command line) add `-prof async:output=flamegraph` option.

When benchmarking completes, JMH will generate a profiler report in .html format:

[image: JMH profile]

If you want to get a flat profile - just methods with the percentage of CPU time spent - use `async` profiler without `output` option:

```
          ns  percent  samples  top
  ----------  -------  -------  ---
  1992741308   39.53%      200  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto
   844434060   16.75%       84  java.util.stream.StreamOpFlag.isKnown
   670418795   13.30%       67  java.lang.Integer.max
   500609106    9.93%       50  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.getStreamAndOpFlags
   451255844    8.95%       45  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate
   221004309    4.38%       22  java.util.stream.ReduceOps$7.makeSink
   140062540    2.78%       14  java.util.Spliterators$IntArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining
    60012022    1.19%        6  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapSink
    39966227    0.79%        4  java.util.stream.ReduceOps$6ReducingSink.accept
    39348309    0.78%        4  java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential
    10862017    0.22%        1  Dictionary::find(unsigned int, Symbol*, Handle)
    10637320    0.21%        1  ciVirtualCallTypeData::translate_from(ProfileData const*)
    10209263    0.20%        1  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.<init>
    10155044    0.20%        1  java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining
    10128043    0.20%        1  PhaseChaitin::Register_Allocate()
    10115108    0.20%        1  _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore_[k]
     9486501    0.19%        1  PhaseChaitin::Select()
     9281194    0.18%        1  PhaseIdealLoop::optimize(PhaseIterGVN&, LoopOptsMode)
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer, this fits my needs!